# Meteor loginWithFacebook gives "internal service error"

Tags: facebook, meteor

I am trying to set up a simple Facebook login, but getting an "internal service error" message when I login.  I've done the following:

1. Added the accounts-ui, accounts-facebook, and ServiceConfiguration packages.
2. Included the standard {{loginButtons}} drop down in my navbar.
3. Include a "login with facebook" button that calls Meteor.loginWithFacebook on my loginpage.
4. Setup a facebook developer account to obtain an app-id and secret.
5. Added the following code to configurations.js file in my server folder:

   ```
   ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
     service: 'facebook'
   });

   ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
     service: 'facebook',
     appId: 'my_app_id,
     secret: 'my_secret'
   });
   ```

Any ideas why I get an "Internal server error"?

Comment: Thank you!  The server console showed the specific error - I had been looking on the client trace.  If you change this to an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add `accounts-ui` package, you do not need to add configurations manually, it'd ask you to enter those credentials from the UI when you visit for the first time. and please check your server console for the error details.